# Create a spinning google map

Tags: html, css, keyframe

So I am attempting to use keyframes to make a spinning google map similar to the example spinning globes you find easily on the internet. So far my google map is behind my "globe" (circle with shading) and moving to the right, but I don't know how to connect the right side of the map to the left side so it doesn't show white space before it starts its animation over (I also haven't hidden the unneeded areas of the map that go outside of the "globe" either, but I'm not worried about that).

I was thinking I could do two google maps side by side initially, but they need the #map id to function properly and you can't have more than one id. I'm new to keyframes so I'm hoping I'm just missing a way to easily connect the right side to flow back in with the left side of the map. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

CSS:

```
#mapWrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mapBackground{
  width: 840px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#earth {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 16px 0 40px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0),
  inset -3px 0 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

}

@keyframes rotate {
  from { left: 1px; }
  to { left: 840px; }
}

/*googlemap*/

#map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mapWrapper">
    <div class="content" id="earth">
    </div>
    <div class="mapBackground">
        <div id="map"></div><div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS 'background-repeat' property?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @User 00000. My mapBackground class isn't really a background though since it is just another div with a map in it that is positioned behind my "globe." I might be wrong, but I'm not sure if/how I could do background-repeat on it.